# "Not able to gain root access with sudo" while installing Cisco Packet Tracer 7.0

Tags: permissions, scripts, root, cisco

I am trying to install Cisco Packet Tracer 7.0 on Lubuntu 16.04.2 LTS throught the executable script provided in the tar folder.
Here is the terminal output:

```
root@Brick:~# pwd
/root
root@Brick:~# cd /home/riccardo/Downloads
root@Brick:/home/riccardo/Downloads# ls
PacketTracer70   PacketTracer70_64bit_linux.tar.gz
root@Brick:/home/riccardo/Downloads# cd PacketTracer70
root@Brick:/home/riccardo/Downloads/PacketTracer70# ls
art  backgrounds  bin  eula.txt  extensions  help  install  languages  lib         
saves  set_ptenv.sh  Sounds  templates  tpl.linguist  tpl.packettracer
root@Brick:/home/riccardo/Downloads/PacketTracer70# sudo ./install
[displays eula]   
Do you accept the terms of the EULA? (Y)es/(N)o
Y  
You have accepted the terms to the EULA. Congratulations. Packet Tracer     will now be installed.
Enter location to install Cisco Packet Tracer or press enter for default [/opt/pt]: 
Installing into /opt/pt

Not able to create and copy files to /opt/pt
Should we try to gain root access with sudo? [Yn] Y
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/opt/pt’: No such file or directory
Not able to gain root access with sudo
Exiting installation
root@Brick:/home/riccardo/Downloads/PacketTracer70#
```

Please note that I'm logged in as root. Running the script with

```
sudo ./install
```

or

```
sudo bash ./install
```

or

```
sudo su
./install
```

produces the same results.

Here I've copied and pasted the contents of the install text script:

```
#!/bin/bash
Thanks to Felix Wolf (felix@bar.bz) for providing this install script.
Thanks to Paul Fedele for providing script to check/download 32-bit library on a 64-bit machine
initInstall ()
{
echo
echo Welcome to Cisco Packet Tracer 7.0 Installation
echo
echo Read the following End User License Agreement \"EULA\" carefully. You must accept the terms of this EULA to install and use Cisco Packet Tracer.
echo "Press the Enter key to read the EULA."
echo
read cont
more eula.txt
echo "Do you accept the terms of the EULA? (Y)es/(N)o"
echo
read input  
case "$input" in
yes|YES|Yes|Y|y)
(installer);;
esac
exit 0
}
installer ()
{
SDIR=`dirname $_`
ARCHITECTURE=$(uname -m)
INSTALL_32BIT_LIBRARY=false
echo "You have accepted the terms to the EULA. Congratulations. Packet Tracer will now be installed."
read -p "Enter location to install Cisco Packet Tracer or press enter for default [/opt/pt]: " IDIR
if [ -z $IDIR ]; then
IDIR="/opt/pt"
fi
if [ $ARCHITECTURE != "x86_64" ]; then  
echo "Packet Tracer must be installed on a 64-bit OS."; exit 0
fi
if [ -e $IDIR ]; then
read -p "It appears that Packet Tracer is already installed.  Do you wish to replace it? [Yn] " NEEDREPLACE
if [ "$NEEDREPLACE" = "y" ] || [ "$NEEDREPLACE" = "Y" ] || [ -z $NEEDREPLACE ]; then
sudo rm -rf $IDIR
else
echo "Program Terminated"; exit 0
fi
fi
QIDIR=${IDIR//\//\\\\\/}
echo Installing into $IDIR
if mkdir $IDIR > /dev/null 2>&1; then
if cp -r $SDIR/* $IDIR; then
echo Copied all files successfully to $IDIR
fi
sh -c "sed s/III/$QIDIR/ $SDIR/tpl.packettracer > $IDIR/packettracer"
chmod a+x $IDIR/packettracer
sh -c "sed s/III/$QIDIR/ $SDIR/tpl.linguist > $IDIR/linguist"
chmod a+x $IDIR/linguist
if touch /usr/share/applications/pt7.desktop > /dev/null 2>&1; then
echo -e "[Desktop Entry]\nExec=PacketTracer7\nIcon=pt7\nType=Application\nTerminal=false\nName=Packet Tracer 7.0" | tee /usr/share/applications/pt7.desktop > /dev/null
rm -f /usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/pt7.png
gtk-update-icon-cache -f -q /usr/share/icons/hicolor
sleep 10
cp $SDIR/art/app.png /usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/pt7.png
gtk-update-icon-cache -f -q /usr/share/icons/hicolor
fi
else
echo
echo Not able to create and copy files to $IDIR
read -p "Should we try to gain root access with sudo? [Yn] " QSD
if [ "$QSD" = "y" ] || [ "$QSD" = "Y" ] || [ -z $QSD ]; then
if sudo mkdir $IDIR; then
echo Installing into $IDIR
if sudo cp -r $SDIR/* $IDIR; then
echo Copied all files successfully to $IDIR
else
echo
echo Not able to copy files to $IDIR
echo Exiting installation
exit
fi
sudo sh -c "sed s/III/$QIDIR/ $SDIR/tpl.packettracer > $IDIR/packettracer"
sudo chmod a+x $IDIR/packettracer
sudo sh -c "sed s/III/$QIDIR/ $SDIR/tpl.linguist > $IDIR/linguist"
sudo chmod a+x $IDIR/linguist
if sudo touch /usr/share/applications/pt7.desktop; then
echo -e "[Desktop Entry]\nExec=PacketTracer7\nIcon=pt7\nType=Application\nTerminal=false\nName=Packet Tracer 7.0" | sudo tee /usr/share/applications/pt7.desktop > /dev/null
sudo rm -f /usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/pt7.png
sudo gtk-update-icon-cache -f -q /usr/share/icons/hicolor
sleep 10
sudo cp $SDIR/art/app.png /usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/pt7.png
sudo gtk-update-icon-cache -f -q /usr/share/icons/hicolor
fi
else
echo
echo Not able to gain root access with sudo
echo Exiting installation
exit
fi
else
echo
echo Exiting installation
exit
fi
fi
echo
echo 
read -p "Should we create a symbolic link \"packettracer\" in /usr/local/bin for easy Cisco Packet Tracer startup? [Yn] " QC
if [ "$QC" = "y" ] || [ "$QC" = "Y" ] || [ -z $QC ]; then
if [ "$user" != "root" ]; then
sudo ln -sf $IDIR/packettracer /usr/local/bin
else 
ln -sf $IDIR/packettracer /usr/local/bin
fi
echo "Type \"packettracer\" in a terminal to start Cisco Packet Tracer"
else
echo "Type \"$IDIR/packettracer\" in a terminal to start Cisco Packet Tracer"
fi
add the environment var PT5HOME
sudo sh set_ptenv.sh $IDIR
echo
echo Cisco Packet Tracer 7.0 installed successfully
}
initInstall
exit 0
```

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Try to create the `/opt` folder before running the script: `sudo mkdir /opt`

Comment: Wow. That did the trick. Thank you for helping me out. I'm posting your suggestion below as an answer so that I can mark this question as "solved".
I find curious that the sudoed script couldn't for the life of it create the /opt, but had no problem  creating the /pt subfolder (in /opt/pt) once /opt is there. 
Anyway, thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was solved by manually creating the /opt folder, with:

```
sudo mkdir /opt
```

before running the installation script.

Thanks and credits to @GunnarHjalmarsson for providing this answer (you can find his original answer in the comment above).

Comment: The script misses the `-p` option to `mkdir`, which explains why this made a difference.